# vb TCP client application breaks trying to read server response

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

Can anyone tell me why my code freezes up at "Return sockReader.ReadLine()"? Thank you. I'm trying to get information back from my Raspberry Pi server when I send a command using "Public Sub Send" and the code is getting stuck.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO

Public Class TCPControl
    Public sock As TcpClient
    Public DataStream As StreamWriter
    Public DataGet As TcpListener
    Private netStream As NetworkStream
    Private sockReader As StreamReader

    Public Sub New(Host As String, Port As Integer)
        ' CLIENT
        sock = New TcpClient(Host, Port)
        netStream = sock.GetStream()
        sockReader = New StreamReader(netStream)
        DataStream = New StreamWriter(sock.GetStream)
        Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("172.16.2.104")
        DataGet = New TcpListener(localAddr, 6969)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Send(Data As String)
        DataStream.Write(Data & vbCrLf)
        DataStream.Flush()
    End Sub

    Public Function Receive()
        Dim howMany As Integer = sock.Available()
        If netStream.DataAvailable Then
            Return sockReader.ReadLine()
        End If
        Return howMany
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The `ReadLine()` method blocks until it has read a whole line. Are you sure that a line break is included in the response? By the way your `Receive()` method doesn't make any sense. It will either return the read string, or `0` if no data is available. Stick to one return type and set `Option Strict On`.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! I was using \0 but \n\r are the line break characters. Please forgive my noobiness :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! I voted to close this question as caused by a typographical error.